# Tring to implement bootstrap.chosen in MVC 5 Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, jquery-chosen

I have installed bootstrap.chosen in my web project and am tring to implement it.

BundleConfig

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/bootstrap-chosen.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
(Top) @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

(Bottom) @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
         @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
         @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

In my razor page i have the following

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HASSForm.HASS_District_Id, new SelectList(Model.HASSDistricts, "Id", "ENGL_NAME"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" } })
```

At the bottom of the page i have the following

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".chosen-select").chosen();
    });
</script>
}
```

I expect the drop down to render with a search box but i only get the regular dropdownlist.

If anyone can help me it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest starting the project from scratch, there is a useful [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kc7XlRPSYCA).

And I push a sample solution to [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ChrisWong2021/searchabledropdownexample/src/master/).